# How can I help Google's Closure Compiler optimize my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

I've been tinkering with Google's Closure Compiler and was able to get everything compiling perfectly using the advanced compilation option.  How can I get the best compilation results from my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about [Advanced compilation](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3.html).